# Mapeamento Fluent NxN de Classes com chave composta

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, fluent-api

Tenho duas classes que tem chaves primárias compostas, exemplo:

`Cliente`:

```cs
public class Cliente
{
    public int EscritorioId { get; set; }
    public virtual Escritorio Escritorio { get; set; }

    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class ClienteMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<Cliente>
{
    public ClienteMapping()
    {
        HasKey(x => new { x.Id, x.EscritorioId });
    }
}
```

`Documento`:

```cs
public class Documento
{
    public int EscritorioId { get; set; }
    public virtual Escritorio Escritorio { get; set; }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Cliente> ClientesComAcesso { get; set; }
}
```

E no mapeamento da classe `Documento` possuo um mapeamento **NxN**:

```cs
public class DocumentoMapping: EntityTypeConfiguration<Documento>
{
    public DocumentoMapping()
    {
        HasKey(x => new { x.EscritorioId, x.Id });

        HasMany(x => x.Clientes)
            .WithMany()
            .Map(m => 
            {
                x.MapLeftKey("EscritorioId", "DocumentoId");
                x.MapLeftKey("EscritorioId", "ClienteId");
                x.ToTable("DocumentoClientes");
            });
    }
}
```

Pois um cliente pode ser destinatário/ter acesso a vários documentos.

Porém, ao tentar gerar o arquivo de *Migrations* para esse caso eu recebo o seguinte erro:

> The specified association foreign key columns 'DocumentoId' are invalid. The number of columns specified must match the number of primary key columns.

Tentando dar outro nome para as chaves compostas, como `Documento_EscritorioId` e `Cliente_EscritorioId`, por exemplo:

```cs
HasMany(x => x.Clientes)
    .WithMany()
    .Map(m => 
    {
        x.MapLeftKey("Documento_EscritorioId", "DocumentoId");
        x.MapLeftKey("Cliente_EscritorioId", "ClienteId");
        x.ToTable("DocumentoClientes");
    });
```

Funciona, mas nesse caso temos uma redundância.

**Qual a forma correta de fazer esse mapeamento?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não vejo necessidade de usar `EntityTypeConfiguration` pra algo tão simples. Os *Models* podem ficar assim:

```
public class Cliente
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int EscritorioId { get; set; }

    public virtual Escritorio Escritorio { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<DocumentoCliente> DocumentosComAcesso { get; set; }
}

public class Documento
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int EscritorioId { get; set; }

    public virtual Escritorio Escritorio { get; set; }    
    public virtual ICollection<DocumentoCliente> ClientesComAcesso { get; set; }
}
```

Acho mais interessante criar a entidade associativa, mesmo que inicialmente pareça prolixo. O ganho no desenvolvimento é maior, até porque você pode colocar mais campos inerentes à associação em si:

```
public class DocumentoCliente 
{
    [Key]
    public int DocumentoClienteId { get; set; }
    [Index("IUQ_DocumentoCliente_DocumentoId_ClienteId", IsUnique = true, Order = 1)]
    public int DocumentoId { get; set; }
    [Index("IUQ_DocumentoCliente_DocumentoId_ClienteId", IsUnique = true, Order = 2)]
    public int ClienteId { get; set; }

    public virtual Documento Documento { get; set; }
    public virtual Cliente Cliente { get; set; }
}
```

[`[Index]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.indexattribute(v=vs.113).aspx), introduzido nesta forma a partir do Entity Framework 6.1.0, garante a unicidade do registro associativo. Validações adicionais podem ser necessárias na aplicação para evitar erros estranhos de duplicidade de chave para o usuário.